# Read multiple CSV files from multiple folder and import to a SQL table through SSIS

Tags: ssis, foreach-loop-container

I have a main folder(Digikala) and every day, a new folder by date name will be added to the main folder. In these folders I have multiple CSV files, I need to read the folder named with the current date every day and insert the 10charchter of each CSV file name as a new column in my table in SQL. How can I do that in SSIS? I know the solution in "For each loop" but I can do this only for one of the folders, As I mentioned it is a daily task, and I need to do it dynamically because the number of folders increases every dy and the number of files inside them is unspecified.
Best regadrs

I have tried "For each loop" in SSIS and name variable (to extract 10 characters) but I can do this only for one of the folders and I should specify the path on the folder manually. As I mentioned it is a daily task.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Use C# script task to find the core folder, then loop through the parent folder using C#,  to find each sub folder then pull that path out, and loop through each file in the folder you want to grab, do your work, and move to the next one.  You can do this in for each loop for each file from C# script task, then pull out the file name/path and pass it to data flow task only the ones you want to loop through.

Hard to give examples without knowing your existing setup.